# How can I clear two FastLEDs strip ws2812b separately? One strip is connected to pin 7 of UNO and other strip to pin 6 of UNO

Tags: arduino-mega, ws2812

The power supply is external. I want to clear one strip say pin 7, and meanwhile i dont want other strip say pin 6 to switch off...I use
FastLED.clear();
FastLED.show();
But it clears all the led strips connected to pin6 and pin7. What is the code to switch off only one strip?

Answer (score 1):

You can use two `CLEDController` instances, which you can control separately, and by using the `clearLedData` you can clear either one or the other LED strip (depending on the `CLEDController` instance).

Below is the code I copied from
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/xrads-fastled-fastled-clear-question/693569/8
which contains more info:

```
#include <FastLED.h>

#define COLOR_ORDER GRB
#define LED_TYPE WS2812B

#define DATA_PIN 9
#define NUM_LEDS 26
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

#define HEADLIGHTS 10   //headlight led pin
#define NUM_HEADLIGHTS 2
CRGB leds2[NUM_HEADLIGHTS];

CLEDController &ledController = FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE, DATA_PIN, COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
CLEDController &headlightController =   FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE, HEADLIGHTS, COLOR_ORDER>(leds2, NUM_HEADLIGHTS);

void setup() {
  ledController.setCorrection(TypicalLEDStrip);
  headlightController.setCorrection(TypicalLEDStrip);

  ledController.clearLedData();
  headlightController.clearLedData();
  FastLED.show();
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michel it worked wonderful!!